# Why is my SSL certificate untrusted on Android?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, mod-ssl

The SSL certificate is trusted on most Desktop computers, but only some Android devices. However, even on Android devices where the certificate is untrusted, the root certificate is installed.

I must have tried a hundered ways of resolving this problem, but I think it has something to do with the *AddTrust External CA Root* (perhaps to do with the *SHA-256* fingerprint, which is missing?).

- The cause does not appear to be an incorrect Certificate Authority Bundle.
- The cause does not appear to be related to time.
- All online SSL checker tools I've used (e.g., https://www.ssllabs.com) say the SSL certificate is installed correctly.
- The root certificate is located on my Android device and on my Desktop computer (see the SHA1 fingerprint in the two screenshots, which is identical).

[image: The root certificate is installed on the Android.]
[image: The root certificate is installed on my Desktop.]

**EDIT 1**

I believe I have included the new intermediary certificate in my certificate chain, but SSL labs is still reporting that it's not present (even after clicking the "Clear cache" button).

[image: Browser refresh includes new SSL certificate chain.]
[image: SSLLabs refresh does not see the new SSL certificate chain.]

**EDIT 2**

To be explicit about what I've done:

1. I've signed into to WHM and clicked the "Install an SSL Certificate on a Domain" option.
2. I've entered the domain name "www.angusaustralia.com.au".
3. I've entered the IP address "27.124.127.2".
4. I've entered the certificate issued to me.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

5. I've entered the private key (not listed below).
6. I've entered the following certificate key chain (many combinations of the below, but I believe this "longer" keychain should work, as per the discussion on the SSLLabs website). This keychain includes the older "USERTrust RSA Certification Authority", which should be trusted by older devices.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

7. Now, it *appears* as if SSLLabs is caching the old result, because when I clear everything from Chrome on my Mac (from the "beginning of time"), the new certificate chain above is detected, as per my previous edit.

**EDIT 3**

The answer Michael Hampton gave was correct. However, the reason why the solution he proposed didn't work was because [WHM has a bug with updating the certificate authority bundle](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9772/69/ca-bundle-is-not-updated-after-reinstalling-certificate-through-cpanel). When this bug occurs, no matter what text you paste into the *Certificate Authority Bundle* field (on the *SSL/TLS -> Install an SSL Certificate on a Domain* page), the contents will be replaced with a different CA bundle *despite WHM giving you a success message*.

Comment: What is the domain in question?

Comment: https://www.angusaustralia.com.au/

Comment: You believe you've added it to your chain, but obviously you haven't. If you actually want help with this, please tell us exactly what you actually did.

Comment: OK, that _seems_ right. But we can't support cPanel here for a variety of reasons. Your next stop should be cPanel support.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take it up with them. Trying to get information from the SSL provider was a joke.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your domain's certificate has two paths to two different root certificate authorities.

On modern desktop browsers such as Google Chrome, as well as on newer Android versions, the path being taken is to the more recent USERTrust RSA Certification Authority root certificate. (I get this on Android 7.0 NPD90G.)

On older Android versions, the path being taken is to the older AddTrust External CA Root root certificate.

On this second path, you are missing an intermediate certificate. This is the one shown in the SSL Labs test as an "Extra download". In order to resolve the problem, you need to obtain this intermediate certificate and add it to the certificate chain in your web server.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer. How can I obtain the other intermediate certificate? I downloaded the intermediate CRT file from here (http://crt.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt), but it contains binary data rather than the usual "--BEGIN CERTIFICATE ... END CERTIFICATE--" text.

Comment: (Note, I obtained that URL from looking at the Authority Information Access section.)

Comment: That looks like the right intermediate cert, but it looks like it's in binary DER format. I was able to convert it with `openssl x509 -inform der -in USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt -out USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.pem`

Comment: I must have tried a hundered different configurations, without any luck. I found some useful resources and tried to add the fix you suggested (see https://community.qualys.com/thread/12831). Still no luck. Any further ideas?

Comment: @user1420752 As previously mentioned, you need to add it to your web server's certificate chain. You haven't done this yet.

Comment: This IS the correct answer. However, see *EDIT 3* above for an explanation on a bug whereby WHM does not allow the updating of the CA bundle, despite reporting that it does.